# IntelliJ Debugger "runs" forever

Tags: java, debugging, input, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ 14, I have code that reads an input from a Scanner that reads System.in, places it into a String ArrayList _buffer and then accesses characters from the buffer. The debugging only starts after I've typed a complete line, so it should not be looking for any more input. When I run the file by command line or Eclipse, it works fine. When I debug the program in IntelliJ, if I step into the line that starts this whole process of reading tokens (and step into each one of its functions), it works fine.

But if I step over this line, IntelliJ acts as if the program is still running and locks me out of debugging. However, nothing should actually be happening.

What could the problem be?

Comment: Providing the code would be a start.

Comment: It's quite a lot of code, but I suppose.

Comment: Trim it down. Create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), a small example that demonstrates the problem. Doing that not only helps us, but frequently you find the problem by creating it.

Comment: What I can say so far is that it the bug only occurs when I set a method breakpoint. If I use a line breakpoint somewhere in the function, before I step over the line, it works. I'm trying to find an easy way to show this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! Turning off "Watch method return values" in the debugger solved the problem. I couldn't tell you why for the life of me! Thanks IntelliJ.